# CSV rowcount breaks ThreadPool

Tags: python, csv, threadpool

I am having a quite strange problem with CSV's and threadpool in Python 2.7
Whenever I try to count the amount of rows in the CSV my thread won't start. Uncommented the code works without any problems.

```
import csv
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

ifile = open('unzipped/49619.txt', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter='|')



#totalrows = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(ifile, delimiter='|'))
totalrows = 111907
print totalrows

def test(args):
    print 'Yes!'

pool = ThreadPool(processes=500)
job_args = [(totalrows, i) for i, row in enumerate(reader)]
pool.map(test, job_args)
```

The result of the count of the commented row is the same as the amount below it, 111907, even the type is the same.

Is this some kind of strange bug or what is going wrong?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? When you uncomment the line in your question above the program doesn't seem to do anything? I'd put a `print job_args` right before the `pool.map` and try on both situations. I'm guessing that the commented line "consumes" the `ifile`, so when you call `enumerate(reader)`, there's nothing left to read. Also, you can try to put a `ifile.seek(0)` to "rewind" the file offset right before the `job_args = [(totalrows...` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your commented line you're iterating over the reader, which will consume your input file. It doesn't matter that you use two different readers, the read position of the file will be at the end.

One solution would be to call `ifile.seek(0)` to rewind the input file before the second iteration.